# Django валидация ajax форм

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, веб-программирование

В своем тренировочном проекте столкнулся с следующей проблемой. В проекте есть старницы где формы подгружаются динамически в виде таблице с произвольным количеством полей. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает информация в БД записывается формы подгружаются, но есть две проблемы.

- 1) Валидация полей работает, информация не записывается в БД если не
  прошла валидацию, но я не понимаю как это сообщить пользователю, на
  данный момент пользователь никак не оповещается о том что он ввел
  непарвильную информацию в формы.
- 2) При отправки формы в консоль вываливаются ошибки непонятной
  природы, на что влияют данные ошибки установить не удалось. Вывод ошибки очень длинный, но

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Код Forms.py

```
class OperationAssembly(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    quantity_of_fileds = kwargs.pop('quantity_of_fileds')
    self.current_user_id = kwargs.pop('current_user_id')
    super(OperationAssembly, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["start_date"] = forms.DateTimeField(initial=now, label='Дата сборки')
    self.fields['type_of_defect'] = forms.CharField(initial="Годная", label='Причина отбраковки', required=False)
    self.fields['serial_number'] = forms.CharField(label="Серийный номер")
    self.fields['type_of_product'] = ModelChoiceField_Label2(queryset=Type_of_product.objects.all(),
                                                             empty_label=None, label="Тип изделия")
    for i in range(1, quantity_of_fileds + 1):
        self.fields["Component {}".format(i)] = forms.CharField(label="С/Н Компонента №{}".format(i))

def clean_type_of_defect(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['type_of_defect']
    if data == '':
        return 3
    else:
        return Type_of_defect.objects.get_or_create(label=data)[0].id

def clean(self):
    super(OperationAssembly, self).clean()
    # Сравниваю каждое поле с каждым на повторы
    for field1, field2 in itertools.combinations(self.fields, 2):
        if self.cleaned_data[field1] == self.cleaned_data[field2]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Поля формы не должны повторяться")

def list_of_assembly(self):
    list_components = []
    for k in self.fields:
        if k.startswith("Component"):
            list_components.append(self.cleaned_data[k])
    # Получаем словарь с списком последних id из внесенных деталей
    temp_query = Product.objects.filter(serial_number__in=list_components).values('serial_number').annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
    return temp_query

def save(self):
    add_product = Product.objects.create(serial_number=self.cleaned_data['serial_number'],
                                         type_of_product_id_id=self.cleaned_data['type_of_product'].id)
    add_product.save()
    new_product_id = add_product.id
    list_of_assembly = self.list_of_assembly()
    for i in list_of_assembly:
        connection.cursor().execute('insert into "mainapp_product_Assembly" (from_product_id, to_product_id)'
                                    ' values ({},{});'.format(new_product_id, i["max_id"]))
    add_operation = Operation_history.objects.create(start_date=self.cleaned_data['start_date'],
                                                     end_date=self.cleaned_data['start_date'],
                                                     employess_id_id=self.current_user_id.id,
                                                     type_of_defect_id_id=self.cleaned_data['type_of_defect'],
                                                     type_of_operation_id_id=6)
    add_operation.save()
    list_of_char = Characteristic_of_product.objects.filter(type_of_product_id_id=self.cleaned_data['type_of_product'].id)
    for char in list_of_char:
        add_char = Product_2_characteristic.objects.create(value="NULL",
                                                           characteristic_of_product_id_id=char.id,
                                                           operation_history_id_id=add_operation.id,
                                                           product_id_id=add_product.id)
        add_char.save()
```

Код views.py

```
def operation_assembly_form(request, quantity_of_fields):
current_form = str(base64.b64encode(bytearray(str(uuid.uuid4()).encode("utf-8"))))[2:-1]
if request.method == "GET":
    form = OperationAssembly(quantity_of_fileds=quantity_of_fields,
                             current_user_id=Employess.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id))
elif request.method == "POST":
    form = OperationAssembly(request.POST, quantity_of_fileds=quantity_of_fields,
                             current_user_id=Employess.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id))
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_json(), content_type='application/json')
return render(request, 'operation_assembly_form.html', {'form': form, 'current_form': current_form,
                                                        'quantity_of_fields': quantity_of_fields})
```

Код подгружаемого html блока

```
    <div id="{{ current_form }}">
<form class="allforms" id="operation_formset" method="POST" action="/mainapp/add/operation/assembly/form/{{ quantity_of_fields }}/">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
        <td>
        {{ form.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
        <td>
        {{ form.errors }}
        {{ field }}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td>
        <button type="button" id="{{ current_form }}_plus" class="btn btn-light">+</button>
        </td>
        <script>
            $('#{{ current_form }}_plus').on('click', function() {
                $.get('/mainapp/add/operation/assembly/form/' + ({{ quantity_of_fields }} + 1) + '/', function(data) {
                    $('#{{ current_form }}').html(data);
                });
                });
        </script>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Код основной html старницы

```
    {% extends "operation_menu.html" %}

{% block chosen_operation %}
<h1>Провести операции:</h1>
    <div id="add_form"></div>
    <button id="plus" class="btn btn-light">+</button>
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-light">Внести информацию о изделиях</button>
    <script>
    $('#plus').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'form/1',
           success: function(data){
           $('#add_form').append(data);
           }
        });
    });
    $("#save").click(function(){
        $('.allforms').each(function(){
            valuesToSend = $(this).serialize();
            form_id = $(this).find('button');
            $.ajax($(this).attr('action'),
                {
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: valuesToSend,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    console.log(form_id.attr('id').slice(0, 48))
                    console.log($(this).attr('action'))
                    if (data.__all__) {
                        $.get($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
                        $('#form_id').html(data);
                    });
          }
        }
                }
            )
        });

    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    response = {}
    for k in form.errors:
        response[k] = form.errors[k][0]
    return JsonResponse({"response": response, 'result': 'error'})
```

В **js**-файл в `ajax` запрос в `success` добавьте условие

```
if (data.result == 'error') {
  //Логика для вывода ошибок
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, json респонс работает, но это значит что мне нужно руками прописывать ререндер формы с отображаемой ошибкой. В более простых формах моего проекта django делает это автоматически, достаточно просто в нужном месте кода страницы указать field.erros. Скажите возможно ли перерендарить в таком же духе форму в этом случае?

Comment: я через скрипт в цикле по `data.response` вытаскивал нужное мне поле из формы и добавлял к нему соответствующую ошибку, которая приходила с сервера в `json`-е. Завтра постараюсь показать этот скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент нужного эффекта в поведении формы я добился следующим кодом.

views.py

```
def operation_assembly_form(request, quantity_of_fields):
current_form = str(base64.b64encode(bytearray(str(uuid.uuid4()).encode("utf-8"))))[2:-1]
if request.method == "GET":
    form = OperationAssembly(quantity_of_fileds=quantity_of_fields,
                             current_user_id=Employess.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id))
elif request.method == "POST":
    form = OperationAssembly(request.POST, quantity_of_fileds=quantity_of_fields,
                             current_user_id=Employess.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id))
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
return render(request, 'operation_assembly_form.html', {'form': form, 'current_form': current_form,
                                                        'quantity_of_fields': quantity_of_fields})
```

Код общего шаблона страницы.

```html
{% extends "operation_menu.html" %}

{% block chosen_operation %}
<h1>Провести операции:</h1>
    <div id="add_form"></div>
    <button id="plus" class="btn btn-light">+</button>
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-light">Внести информацию о изделиях</button>
    <script>
    $('#plus').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'form/1',
           success: function(data){
           $('#add_form').append(data);
           }
        });
    });
    $("#save").click(function(){
        Can_i_redirect = 0
        $('.allforms').each(function(){
            valuesToSend = $(this).serialize();
            form_id = $(this).find('button');
            $.ajax($(this).attr('action'),
                {
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: valuesToSend,
                context:this,
                async:false,
                success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.slice(63, -6))
                    $(this).html(data.slice(63, -6));
                    console.log(data.indexOf('errorlist'))
                    if (data.indexOf('errorlist') != -1) {
                        Can_i_redirect += 1
                        console.log(Can_i_redirect)
                    }
          }
        });
        console.log(Can_i_redirect)
        if (Can_i_redirect == 0) {
           $(location).attr('href','/mainapp/add/operation/assembly/')
        }
    });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Код вставляемых шаблонов.

```html
    <div id="{{ current_form }}">
    <form class="allforms" id="operation_formset" method="POST" action="/mainapp/add/operation/assembly/form/{{ quantity_of_fields }}/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            {% for field in form %}
            <td>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for field in form %}
            <td>
            {{ field }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td>
            <button type="button" id="{{ current_form }}_plus" class="btn btn-light">+</button>
            </td>
            <script>
                $('#{{ current_form }}_plus').on('click', function() {
                    $.get('/mainapp/add/operation/assembly/form/' + ({{ quantity_of_fields }} + 1) + '/', function(data) {
                        $('#{{ current_form }}').html(data);
                    });
                    });
            </script>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```